# array_contains for type JsonNullableFilter issue

Tags: node.js, prisma

I'm new to nodejs prisma when I have JSON array in database and I'm trying to filter data. I'm getting this error:-

> array_contains for type JsonNullableFilter

Answer (score 0):

We have to enable filterJson preview feature

> Prisma Client preview feature

1. Add the Preview feature flag to the generator block: `generator client { provider = "prisma-client-js" previewFeatures = ["filterJson"] }`
2. in the terminal,
   `run npx prisma generate`

You can refer from official documentation: [Prisma Client and schema preview features](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/preview-features/client-preview-features)